# iOS - Does Changing App Name Change Link?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We are preparing to submit a renamed version of our app.

We're using the SLComposeViewController to allow the user to share our app socially, and have the link to us in iTunes included:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/oldappname/idoldappid?ls=1&mt=8

Will renaming the app change 'oldappname'? If so, how can we account for this when submitting the app. I'm assuming 'oldappid' will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

YES, when app is changing the name, the link is changing

Comment: is there any way to know what the link would be BEFORE I submit the build, so I can get the new link into the app?

Comment: Open ItunesConnect/My Apps, Select your app to be submitted. In the menu, there's view on app store, and when you click it, it will show the link on browser

Comment: doing that just shows the link for the current build (old name)

Comment: is that new version with name changed?

Comment: under further investigation, apparently using the link format : https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idxxxxxxxxxx?ls=1&mt=8 works fine. Don't need the app name in there